# yarn link not picking up local dependency version change

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I'm working on an app that relies on a dependency we also manage. I use *yarn link* to tell my app to use the local dependency and all this worked well with my recent changes. (I did not increment the version number of the dependency).

Then another team member carried out some work on the same dependency, bumped the version number from **0.4.0** to **0.5.0** and pushed it to our develop branch. All tests passed, HUZZAH!

I pulled this update and merged to my feature branch and *yarn build* and I can confirm that the changes are present. I then adjusted my app's package.json to look for the new **0.5.0** version, delete the *node_modules* folder and *yarn install* to get the update but *yarn* keeps throwing up it cannot find version **0.5.0** and then lists all previous versions available.

I have wasted hours on this and I have no idea why this is happening, has anyone seen this before and have a solution?

Comment: Hello there :-) Have you found what's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

We gave up on `yarn link` and use [yalc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yalc) which has worked perfectly since this question was created.
This is a decent [guide](https://www.viget.com/articles/how-to-use-local-unpublished-node-packages-as-project-dependencies/).